# Remove certain object from Array of Objects swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have array of objects

```
let storeArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

And I want to remove obj2, how can I remove this with Swift 5?

Comment: Did you try anything, have you done any research like reading the documentation for Array?

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to remove obj2, you can do this...

```
var storeArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
storeArray.removeAll(where: { $0 == obj2 })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that obj2 is in index 1 of the array and you trust that:

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
guard array.count > 1 else { return }
array.remove(at: 1)
```

If you want to remove the obj2 without trusting it's index:

```
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
array.removeAll(where: { $0 == obj2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 var storeArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
 storeArray.remove(at: 1)
 print(storeArray)
```